# Redrawing UIButton using CGRectMake doesn't update UIButton position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I'm trying to update the position and size of several UIButtons in my app by using:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _UIButton1.frame = CGRectMake(-7, 35, 212, 77);
    _UIButton2.frame = CGRectMake(139, 149, 290, 77);
    // And so on for several more buttons
}
```

However, when I use this code, these buttons just appear at wherever the location is set on the Storyboard, not where I'm setting it programmatically. How would I make these buttons appear at a location this is different than the one I have set in my Storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your storyboard file and make sure the right pane is showing the Utilities menu, then uncheck `Use Auto Layout`.

When Auto Layout is enabled, you have to set constraints on your views and create outlets to those constraints to move things around with code. If you want to work directly with frames, Auto Layout needs to be turned off. It has to be one or the other.

Auto Layout can be great, but it's hard to make a recommendation without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And it's better to set the frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, so that the buttons are moved *before* they're onscreen.

Comment: So can I only do this if I don't use autoLayout/Size Classes?

Comment: RIght, you have to choose. It may be worth trying to do it with constraints so you aren't manually putting in frame values.

Comment: If I just make new UIButtons programmatically that are not linked to the storyboard this would allow me to keep using size classes and auto layout correct?

Comment: I just tried and it worked so you technically can. It could get hard to keep up with really quickly though for several buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Please update frame in `-(void) viewWillAppear` method as in `viewDidAppear` your view is practically set and is ready to displayed.
after updating your button's frame please use following line of code

`[self.view laoutIfNeeded];`

Thanks